# Returning floating point number from Kibana 4 scripted field

Tags: groovy, elasticsearch, kibana

I need to return a floating point number via a scripted field in Kibana 4 (beta 3).  The scripted field needs to perform a division on an integer ( > 0 ) field stored in the elasticsearch index as in:

```
1 / field-value
```

The scripted fields use Groovy, therefore I tried...

```
1.0 / doc["integer-field"].value
```

...but that doesn't seem to have worked.  I was under the impression that the use of 1.0 would cast the result to a floating point number - I seem to be getting infinity plotted on my line chart.

Totally new to Groovy and Kibana so I've probably got the syntax wrong.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Just to close this off - I have discovered that the scripted field I mentioned in my question does actually work perfectly.  My issues were related to a re-indexing of our data.  I am now using Kibana 4 scripted fields to plot search engine mean reciprocal rank.